# How to force configure script to generate release makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, configure, autoconf

While compiling some libraries (spatialite 3.0.1, geos 3.3.3 and others) I've noticed that running `./configure` results in a makefile that contains lines like this

```
CFLAGS = -g -O2
CXXFLAGS = -g -O2
```

That means that debug symbol generation is enabled by default. What I want is to disable debug compiling mode without manual makefile editing. I've ran `./configure --help` for both of libraries mentioned above, but I have not found any option to get desired result. I feel that the solution should be very simple, but I'm stuck on this since I'm not very familiar with building software from sources.

OS: Linux Red Hat Enterprise 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about autoconf/automake:

Why not just keep the debugging symbols and let anybody who doesn't like them `make install-strip`?

Answer (score 3):

You can pass CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS along with configure script

```
./configure CFLAGS="-O2" CXXFLAGS="-O2"
```